# Howto see messages that are subject to net_ratelimit?

Tags: linux, networking, kernel, logs

OS: Ubuntu 14.04.3
Kernel: 3.13.0

I am running Linux Virtual Server (with keepalived) on that server. All ok. As of today, there is more network traffic on the LVS, and at the same time I start seeing the following Linux kernel log entries (in `/var/log/syslog` or `dmesg`) every few minutes:

```
net_ratelimit: n callbacks suppressed
```

where n is a integer number.

Here:
https://bani.com.br/2015/06/linux-getting-rid-of-net_ratelimit-n-callbacks-suppressed-messages/

is written the solution to disable the kernel network code log message rate limiting with the following command:

```
sysctl -w net.core.message_cost=0
```

After issuing this command, the above mentioned *"callbacks suppressed"* messages do not occur anymore, and the `/var/log/syslog` stays empty as it used to be. Also `dmesg` command does not show anything anymore.

But what I want is to see the messages that have been subject to the log message rate limiting, because I guess there is a network problem that leads to the high amount of log messages. It looks like these messages are not logged. How can I see that messages?